# Test strategy for postgres in the backend

Tags: postgresql, testing

I'd like to test a backend that performs queries agains a Postgres DB. As far as I understand mocking postgres is not possible (as opposed to MongoDB) and one should query a real database.

So my first question is, what are the standard strategies to test postgres queries?

Right now, I'm trying to recreate a database with no data so that I can plug in information for each test and have full control of the output. However, it is not clear how that can be done. So far I've come up with something like:

```
pg_dump mydb --schema-only | pg_restore testdb
```

However it is really slow. I suppose one of the reasons is that if the test client is not in the same net as the database, then pg_dump will have to fetch all the information through the net only to send it back to the same machine.

I suppose what I'm looking for would be similar to

```
Create new database testdb with template mydb
```

which only copied schema info and which didn't force all connections to be closed.

Comment: There's no single "standard" answer for that. It all depends on what you need to test: business logic, queries only, structures, performance etc. There are some frameworks you might find interesting: http://pgtap.org/, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testing.postgresql/, https://github.com/mixerp/plpgunit etc. I've built my own simple framework using NodeJS Mocha, Chai and Lodash and I have pre-defined structure – not taking schema structure from existing DB, but that's specific to my needs and use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of a template database is the best one, I think.

Why don't you create a template database that is the same as `mydb`, only without data? If your problem is that `mydb` undergoes frequent schema changes, use a deployment technique that applies all schema changes to both `mydb` and the template database.